# AttributeError for classes

Tags: python

I'm getting an AttributeError: 'table' object has no attribute 'displayTable' for my code and i'm not sure whats going on

```
import random

class table:
    def  __init__(self, width, length):
        self.width = width
        
        self.length = length
        
        self.frontSide = [["?" for j in range(self.width)] for i in range(self.length)]
        
        self.rearSide = [[" " for j in range(self.width)] for i in range(self.length)]
        
def displayTable(self):
    # prints column numbers
    print("   1     2    3")
    j = 1
    for i in self.frontSide:
        print(j,i)
        j += 1
    print("")

a = table(3,2)

a.displayTable()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent the `displayTable` method the same as the `__init__` method.

```
import random

class table:
    def  __init__(self, width, length):
        self.width = width
        
        self.length = length
        
        self.frontSide = [["?" for j in range(self.width)] for i in range(self.length)]
        
        self.rearSide = [[" " for j in range(self.width)] for i in range(self.length)]
        
    def displayTable(self):
        # prints column numbers
        print("   1     2    3")
        j = 1
        for i in self.frontSide:
            print(j,i)
            j += 1
        print("")

a = table(3,2)

a.displayTable()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your displayTable() definition doesn't belong to class table, because it isn't indented under the class. Try it like this:

```
import random

class table:
    def  __init__(self, width, length):
        self.width = width
        
        self.length = length
        
        self.frontSide = [["?" for j in range(self.width)] for i in range(self.length)]
        
        self.rearSide = [[" " for j in range(self.width)] for i in range(self.length)]
        
    def displayTable(self):
        # prints column numbers
        print("   1     2    3")
        j = 1
        for i in self.frontSide:
            print(j,i)
            j += 1
        print("")

a = table(3,2)

a.displayTable()
```

Both **init** and displayTable now belong to class, and they have the same level of indentation.